# Determine dwell times

Tags: awk, dataset

I have a data set of:

```
32
33
34
35
34
32
29
28
27
25
29
32
34
35
36
28
27
28
28
```

I would like to be able to find out how many numbers in a row are above 32. For example an output like:

```
5
4
```

where 5 is the first instance the values are above 32, and 4 is the second instance the values are over 32. I have been trying to do this in awk but so far all I am getting is the collective number i.e. 9 for all value combined above 32.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add your attempt to the question and also your output should be 4 and 3 according to your description.

Comment: shouldn't the result be `6 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!  I think your output is not consistent with the input, or I misunderstood the problem.  This is computing the chain length of values `>31`

```
$ awk '$1>31{c++; next} c{print c; c=0} END{if(c) print c}' file
6
4
```

`END` block is required for the case if the last chain contains the last element.

Comment: The OP said "above 32", not "greater than or equal to 32". Good approach though.

Comment: Either it's 6,4 or 5,3.  Data and output are not consistent.

Comment: FWIW I agree with [@Quasimodo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61047965/determine-dwell-times/61048386?noredirect=1#comment108001691_61047965) that it should be 4,3.

Comment: You are correct, it should be 4, 3. Sorry for the confusion.